# Running Azure functions across multiple frameworks?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create a REST API using Azure functions and HTTP triggers, but there are dependencies I need to include that require different frameworks, one of which uses .net Framework 4.7.2 and another on a version of .net Core. Is there any way I can separate parts of the program to run in a different framework and be called by other parts of the program.

Comment: Only if you wrap it up into separate exe, for example into small microservice.

Comment: Each function app will run its own environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple projects, one for Core and one for Framework and add dependencies for your azure function. To add Dependencies Click on your Azure functions Project -> Add -> Project References -> Check the required projects.

[image]

For accessing the projects you can perform  `Dependency injection`.

Comment: How can I use dependency injection to access the other project when they are on different frameworks? When I try that I still am unable to load the package that supports .net framework when running the corresponding code in the main .net core project.

Comment: Try creating an instance of the your project and add the reference of the other project.
 Example:
 ```
  Function1 function = new Function1();
        public Function1()
        {
        }

        private static ClassCore _core;
        private static ClassFramework _framework;
        public Function1(ClassCore core)
        {
            _core = core;
        }

        public Function1(ClassFramework framework)
        {
            _framework = framework;
        }
   ```
   ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/B9Cg9jF.png)